# CustomViewCallback cannot be resolved Android

Tags: android, html, webview

I am trying to get an HTML 5 video to play using WebView, but I keep getting this error:

"CustomViewCallback cannot be resolved to a type"

Here is the code:

```
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {  

        public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {  
          super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);  
          if (view instanceof FrameLayout){  
              FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) view;  
              if (frame.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView){  
                  VideoView video = (VideoView) frame.getFocusedChild();  
                  frame.removeView(video);  
                  setContentView(video);  
                  video.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {  

                     @Override  
                     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {  
                         mp.stop();  
                         setContentView(R.layout.mnwv_main);  
                     }  
                 });  
                  video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {  

                     @Override  
                     public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {  
                         return false;  
                     }  
                 });  
                  video.start();  
              }  
          }  
      }  
      }); // new WebChromeClient() ends...  


    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.meanwhileinwv.com");

}
```

Anyone know what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback` is supported since API Level 7 (2.1). So my guess your testing device (or simulator) has lower API level.

Comment: My device is runnning 2.3.3, and the minSDK is 7.

Comment: Ok, what Android API level is used in Eclipse for the project?

Comment: It also could be an Eclipse issue, try call cleanup for the project.

Comment: In eclipse, it was set to API 1.6..... haha. Forgot I changed it for a previous project :P